# Is $K=F_q^2\setminus V(f)$ is a Kakeya set in $F_q^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, kakeya-sets

**Statment**

> Let $q$ the power of a prime number $p$ and $f(x,y)\in F_q[x,y]$ a non constant polynomial, then $K=F_q^2\setminus V(f)$ is a Kakeya set.

My attempt.
I think that it is False, for it let consider the line $L_{v,a}=\lbrace a+kv\mid k\in F_q\rbrace$ be the line that pass throught by $a$ in the direction of $v\neq 0$.

Now let $f(x,y)=y-x$ which vanishes in $y=x$ and chose $v=(3,3)$, $k\in F_q$ and $a=(a_1,a_1)$
then $L_{v,a}=\lbrace (a_1+3k,a_1+3k)\rbrace $ but $a_1+3k-a_1-3k=0$ and hence $L\not \subset  K$.

Hence $K$ isn´t Kakeya set.

I think that is fine, but I have some problems to understand how the line looks.

I understand that in general $F_q^2$ is like a chess board where I have all the squares with a point, but I don´t get which means that the direction of $v\neq 0$ and how looks a line in any direction of some $v$. Thanks any hint or comment was useful.

Comment: What is the definition of a Kakeya set in $\Bbb{F}_q^2$?

Comment: A line is determined when we know a single point $a$ on it (any will do) and its direction (given by a non-zero vector $v$)- just like in $\Bbb{R}^2$! The description of the set $L_{v,a}$ serves as a definition. I don't know what is bothering you about it?

Comment: The line will not change if we replace $a$ with any other point on the line, or if we replace the vector $v$ with its non-zero scalar multiple.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you have somehow misunderstood the definition of a Kakeya set. I have never worked with them, but surely the definition is that to each $v$ there exists an $a$ such that $L_{v,a}$ is contained in the set. It simply cannot be that every line $L_{v,a}$ must be contained. For then the only possible Kakeya set would be the entire space, and the concept would be totally uninteresting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a torus of side $q$ you generally wrap around. It is a wrapped around discrete line.

The $q$ prime case is as below:

For $q=7$ and $a=1,v=1$, write the torus as $\{0,1,\ldots,6\}^2$:

$$
0~1~0~0~0~0~0\\
0~0~1~0~0~0~0\\
0~0~0~0~1~0~0\\
0~0~0~0~0~1~0\\
0~0~0~0~0~0~1\\
1~0~0~0~0~0~0\\
$$

For $q=7$ and $a=5,v=5$
we have $\{5+5k:k\in F_7\}=\{5,3,1,6,4,2,0\}$ which gives
$$
0~0~0~0~0~1~0\\
0~0~0~1~0~0~0\\
0~1~0~0~0~0~0\\
0~0~0~0~0~0~1\\
0~0~0~0~1~0~0\\
0~0~1~0~0~0~0\\
1~0~0~0~0~0~0\\
$$

Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen for catching my mistake, the comment I had before applied only to the prime case:

The nonprime case is equivalent to this, if the elements of $F_q$ are reordered as
$\{0,1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{q-2}\}$ where $g$ is a primitive element (which always exists) and the multiplication by the nonzero elements is just multiplication by powers of $g.$

Comment: The notation $\Bbb{F}_q$ surely means the finite field of $q$ elements, so I don't understand what you mean by divisors of $q$ **as elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$**.